# how to store and retrieve vector data in persistent store BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am developing a BlackBerry app where I need to store the selected songs in persistent store. Later I want to retrieve and delete selected contents. Can anybody suggest me how to store and delete selected songs in persistent store?

Comment: http://m7mdali.blogspot.in/2010/04/persistent-store-in-blackberry.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the guide topic [Storing objects persistently](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29299/Storing_objects_persistently_1554312_11.jsp). It describes the code you need to store a `Vector`, among other things.